# Jackson Data binding model unmarshalling array of objects

Tags: java, json, jackson

Okay I have a JSON file and it has a set of objects that I wish to unmarshal into array of objects.

An example of how the JSON file is laid out is:

```
{
"data":{
  "name":{
     "fName":"John",
     "lName":"Doe"
  },
  "name":{
     "fName":"James",
     "lName":"Dokes"
  }
 }
}
```

The full JSON file is a lot more complex than this, this is just a example of how it is laid out.

What I want to do is to take those names, and unmarshall them into an array of name objects so I can access each name object whenever I want.

The classes are set up as

Test Class

```
 private Data data;

public void setData(Data d) {
    data = d;
}

public Data getData() {
    return data;
}

public String toString() {
    return "" + data;
}
```

Data Class

```
 private Name name;

public void setName(Name n){
    name = n;
}


public Name getName(){
    return name;
}


public String toString(){
    return "Names " + name;
}
```

Then the Name class is just

```
public class Name {

private String fName;
private String lName;

 //Getter setters here

    public String toString(){
    return "\nFirstName: " + fName + "\nLastName: " + lName;
}
```

Then in the main class, I just do

```
 ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    Test test = mapper.readValue(new File("C:\\JSON\\test.json"),
            Test.class);
    System.out.println(test);
```

Now this will print out

```
Names 
FirstName: James
LastName: Dokes
```

But it ignores the first name object, i.e. John Doe. What I want is to take each of these name objects and place them in an ArrayList, that way I can access the information, and display it whenever I want.

What am I doing wrong here? I tried changing the JSON file and making the names into an array, and then changing the code in the Data class and making Names an Array of object Names, but got an error saying

```
 Can not deserialize instance of Data out of START_ARRAY token
```

Would anyone be able to point me in the right direction here, as have tried many different solutions, but no success.

Thanks in advance for any help

EDIT:

Should my JSON look like this then

```
 {
"data":{
   "name":[
      {
         "fName":"John",
         "lName":"Doe"
      },
      {
        "fName":"test",
        "lName":"test2"
     }
   ]
 }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you posted isn't really valid JSON as the `data` object has two keys with the same value `name`. Or rather, this JSON doesn't represent an array of names as your title suggests it should.

If the JSON `data` is meant to be a true JSON object, meaning that it is similar to a hashtable of names to values, then you should represent than in your Java class as a `Map`. But your `Test` class has a single `Data` field, which has a single `Name` field. One instance of `Test` cannot have more than one `Name` in this structure.

Comment: Okay, I updated my post quickly. Should my JSON instead look like the one I updated my post with?

Comment: that JSON looks more logical. To map this to a Java POJO, you'd want to represent the `name` array as a `List<Name>` in your Data class.